# Can a "pseudo" SDE be solved as an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I am not that much into ordinary differential equations.

Assume I have a stochastic process satisfying the "SDE"

$dX_t = (rX_t + Y_t) dt$ with $Y_t$ preferably just some unspecified SDE.

Can it then be concluded immediately from how to solve ODE's that  (assuming I did it right)

$$X_T = X_0 e^{rT} + \int_0^T e^{r(t-s)} Y_s ds$$

or does one have to do something more elaborate? What would be the restriction on $Y$ for it to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "[...] $Y_t$ preferably just some unspecified SDE"?

Comment: I think your approach is correct. One just defines a new process $X_t$ pathwise as per your formula and obtains a process on the same probability space as $Y_t$. The main assumption would be that $Y_t$ is sufficiently regular for the integral to make sense (almost surely). For example, if $Y_t$ has a.s. continuous paths there is no problem. If $Y_t$ is white or colored noise there is a serious problem with this and Ito or Stratonovich calculus is needed.

Comment: That I want to assume very little about $Y_t$ - i.e. just that it follows an Stochastic Differential Equation (in contrast to say e.g. some nasty infinite activity jump process or the like).

Comment: @Henrik I see; so it's simply an Itô process. (Note that an "unspecified SDE" might have jumps. That's why I'm asking.)

Comment: @saz darn. Actually I did not think the term Ito process was commonly used - I guess I should have figured that SDE would not cut it, but that was my lecturer always used to call Ito processes. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @Henrik Well, in fact, there is no standard definition for "Itô process" (depending on the context, it might different things). However, if you are talking about SDEs and Itô processes, everyone will know what you mean.